# ifcase like section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, conditionals

Can I expand `\ifcase`  to two levels:

```
\ifcase{1.1} = a            
\ifcase{1.2} = b 
\ifcase{1.3} = c 
\ifcase{2.1} = a
\ifcase{2.2} = b
.
.
.
\ifcase{3.1} = a
\ifcase{3.2} = b
\ifcase{3.3} = c
```

Naming should follow the second argument as in above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Interpretation: Stripping second part of the number and convert it to a letter

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\SecondAsAlph}[1]{%
  \@alph{\StripToDot#1}%
}
\def\StripToDot#1.{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{#1 = \SecondAsAlph{#1}\par}
\test{1.1}
\test{1.2}
\test{1.3}
\test{2.1}
\test{2.2}
\test{3.1}
\test{3.2}
\test{3.3}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Interpretation: Second part of the (sub)section number is a letter

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter\alph{section}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\alph{subsection}}
```

## Interpretation: `\ifcase` skips the first part of the number

```
\newcommand*{\MyCaseMacro}[1]{% #1 is the number of the form <x>.<y>
  \ifcase\StripToDot#1 %
    % case <x>.0
  \or
    % case <x>.1
  \or
    % case <x>.2
  \or
    % case <x>.3
  \else
    % case <x>.<y> with <y> equal to or greater than 4 (or negative)
  \fi
}
\def\StripToDot#1.{}
```